# Como puedo capturar usando selenium con python este porcentaje?

Tags: html, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Tengo que capturar la expression "0%" usando selenium python.
El código html es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Yo escribí

```
idd = "status-espana-capital_related_risks-nfr-0"
elem=driver.find_element_by_id(idd)
elem.text
```

Pero el resultado fue "In progress", no "0%"
También escribí:

```
elem=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('p.ng-binding')
elem.text
```

Pero obtuve un texto de que aparece en otro sitio de la página web, por lo que no capturé el elemento que quería sino otro con la misma clase 'ng-binding'.

Comment: En vez de buscar el `span` tienes que buscar el elemento `p` que tiene la clase `ng-binding` y obtener su valor ya que `0%` esta como valor dentro del elemento `p`.  Ten en cuenta que esa clase se puede repetir en mas de un elemento.

Comment: @EugeniBejan he actualizado la pregunta añadiendo el resultado de tu sugerencia. Me imprime otro texto de la página, ¿como puedo escoger el elemento con clase "ng-binding" de forma más concreta, puesto que hay más?

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado usando xpath? Sobre la línea del código fuente donde está el 0%, haz click derecho, busca la opción de copiar y dentro "copiar Xpath". Cambia tu código para buscar por xpath en vez de por id:

```
elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath("<pega aquí el xpath>")
elem.text
```

Comment: Lo hice y se me copió `//*[@id="percentage_espana-capital_related_risks-nfr-0"]` e hice `elem=driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='percentage_espana-capital_related_risks-nfr-0']") `pero al hacer `elem.text` me sale cadena vacia